# Multiple cisco 3020 switches

Tags: cisco-catalyst

I have 22 cisco switches in 6 racks (2+4+4+4+4+4).

Inside a rack the switches are daisy-chained. The switch on top every rack is connected to the first switch in the first rack.

```
 +++++
 +++++
++++++
++++++
```

I've tested my setup with a simple daisy-chain of 2 Cisco 3020 and I got no connection to the clients which are attached to the second switch.

If I connect only one swicth, all is fine.

I resetted the Cisco 3020 to default values. As this, all switches became unmanaged (which is fine, there is no much traffic).

How can I get the traffic through all 22 switches?

Comment: All devices should have L2 connectivity if they are physically connected in the manner you described.  All devices must have the correct IP Addresses and Masks to be able to communicate within the same subnet.  All devices must have the correct and reachable Gateway in order to reach devices outside of its subnet.

Comment: If all devices are really in their default configuration, then all ports are in VLAN 1 and should be forwarding.  Check all your switches to see if that's true by entering the command "show spanning-tree vlan 1"

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure each port that is being used to connect each switch to the other switch is configured as a trunk. The ports that your devices plug into will stay access ports. Make sure that the same vlan id is being used in each switch. That should get you going.
For future reference, posting the device config(s) would allow others to generate a more accurate response. Thanks.